# Graphical visualisation tool for AWS Neptune

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, neo4j, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am starting a project with AWS Neptune service which is a TinkerPop/Gremlin implementation and since I am moving over from MySQL to graph db i was curious to know whether there are any workbench kind solutions available while working with AWS neptune since using the gremlin console is not very efficient from the development aspect for a new comer at least. In this regard is Neo4j having more tools which improves the development time and would it be wise to prefer Neo4j over AWS Neptune due to this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try integrating with the GraphExp project:
https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp

Comment: This looks very good .. I did not see an option to run a gremlin query, is that something that might be possible in this tool.